I twisted a 3/8" lag bolt in half. Should that be possible?
A swing on the playset I built earlier this year had a loose bolt, so I went to tighten it and instead of the bolt tightening, I twisted it in half (wrench lever arm 6", bolt diameter 3/8", galvanized steel). Recalling that the bolts came with the swing hangers, and hearing rumors about inferior lag bolts being bundled with swings, I removed the other three bolts. All of them snapped instead of screwing out.
Is this normal -- that someone could twist a bolt in half  without extreme effort -- or are the bolts defective?
If this is a defect, should I expect an identical galvanized steel lag bolt from my local hardware store will be of higher quality?

There are no markings on the heads.

That appears to be defective. I can twist 5/16" stainless steel bolts with a lot of effort (the joy of galling on stainless hardware). 3/8" have 44% more cross-section, and galvanized steel (even for bottom of the barrel bolts) should be harder. You can grab a few generic bolts from the big box store and see how they fair. Perhaps you have super human strength?

I've wrung off 3/8" lag screws just trying to get them tight in a lead anchor in a brick wall.  And no, I'm not a big guy!

That's a good point: I can under-pre-drill a hole in some scrap wood and at least try to break my new bolts before putting them in the playset. I'll try that tonight. I'd love to make this a science experiment with controlled tension, but unfortunately I don't have any more of the suspicious bolts.

Ah yes, the infamous SP Grade lag bolts, imported from the world's hardware store. What they didn't tell you is that SP stands for Silly Putty. Consider replacing all the fasteners for the kids' safety.

This is fairly typical.  use through bolts or structural screws instead.

A lumberyard or "home improvement center" that sells SimpsonStrongTie hardware will often carry SST's vastly superior lag screws as well. This stuff is usually located in the Lumber Department, not the Fastener Department where they have the cheap Chinese lag screws you have encountered.

Bolts were probably made from Chinesium.

A bolt's manufacturer will have torque and tension specs for its components. Good mnufacturers often order parts just strong enough for their intended purpose; it's cheaper that way. So this is possible even with a good bolt if you abuse it enough. Odds are, however, that you ordered from someone who tried to shave a few cents by using questionable hardware. Try contacting them for replacements, or just get your own hardware from a more trustworthy source. It also could just be one defective part.

@Criggie there are no markings on the heads

Get a shorter spanner.

Hardware stores will generally stock whatever provides a good profit.  Their paying less when buying their stock usually helps profitability, unless that impacts whether customers want to buy their products.  Find a hardware store that sells higher quality hardware, and get Grade 5 or Grade 8 (the metric version is 10.1).  Pre-drilling, lubricating (rub them on a bar of soap or paraffin) and not over-torquing fasteners on installation is important.

There are various grades of hardware. Standards, such as SAE J429and  ASTM A307 in the United States, and ISO standards in most other locales, define bolt strength and marking. The lowest SAE J429 Grade, 1, has an unmarked bolt head and is about one quarter as strong as Grade 8, with six radial lines on the head.
For non-critical use in consumer items, it's not surprising that the bolt sheared easily. For that matter, with effort, I've accidentally sheared a 1/2" wheel stud, likely Grade 5 or stronger, with an ordinary tire iron (and had to drive to a garage with one stud missing).
That said, if it sheared easily with a 6" (15 cm) long wrench, likely that bolt was defective, and a new Grade 1 bolt should be stronger.
Use a torque wrench if this happens again.

I put a new Everbilt Grade 1 lag screw into the hardest scrap wood I have lying around and tightened it with the same wrench. I was definitely applying more torque, 40%-80% more, than what severed the cheap ones in the image, and the bolt survived.
So I feel confident saying that the initial bolts are inferior, though I don't know by how much. If I get my hands on some again I'll conduct a proper experiment and update this answer.

is it too soon to post a vid clip here, of the man everyone loves to hate, saying Chyna
https://www.onallcylinders.com/2014/03/13/diagnose-common-fastener-failures/
look up various articles on identifying torsion/shear/tension breakage of fasteners.  that looks like breakage from torsion.  and given the drawn putty look of the metal, very low grade soft metal.... i.e pot metal... chyna (not the wrestler chic)

I don't know whether to +1 for the extremely helpful link or -1 for the extraneous commentary.

my extraneous comment(s) simply point out the root cause you [or anyone offended by such comments] are in denial to.  So be sure to be all... thats so informative but then go buy same junk bolts and have the same thing happen again, and maybe when your kid is swinging the thing lets go and you're kid lawn darts.

you probably have no idea the degree to which counterfeit fraudulent fasteners (that's nuts, bolts, screws) are a problem.

In general, wrenches are designed to a length such that the average person gets about the right torque and doesn't break the bolt. Therefore if you break a bolt with a (non-adjustable) wrench, the bolt was sub-standard.
You can look up the recommended torque for all sorts of bolts in charts like this
There you can see that a steel 3/8" bolt is commonly torqued to about 240 inch-pounds, or 20 foot-pounds.
Bolts are commonly torqued to about 75% of their failure strength, so very roughly 30 foot-pounds. That would be 60 pounds of force with a 6" wrench. You could do that, but I think you'd know you were about to break something.
Having said that, this chart suggests 10 foot-pounds

semi-rhetorical: for a 3/8 lag bolt, let's assume it's actually ASTM or SAE rated, when torqued to 10 lbft and providing ~2000 lbs of clamp force how do you know this is ok to suggest when you don't know the material of the "play set" ?

@ron - I'm not recommending a torque. OP didn't ask for a torque. I'm using standard recommended torques to estimate the breaking torque for good bolts, which I couldn't look up easily. I did this in order to provide some evidence that the supplied bolts were low quality.

Sorry, my english wording is not the best for this terminology.
Bolts are designed to withstand force along the pulling direction, but they are not intended to withstand forces to the side (Of course they withstand a bit).
Usually the the friction between two pieces which you mount with the bolts prevent your bolts to receive sideway forces.
So it can be that your bolts got damaged because they were loose and thus received too much sideway forces.
Edit: Just to be clear, I don't mean that you stressed the bolts in a wrong direction during tightening, I mean that the bolts might got damaged before, while they were loose.
Edit: I just noticed that not all bolts were loose but all bolts broke in the same way. So it is clear that stress to the wrong direction can't be the reason here.

While you have an excellent point, OP managed to sheer the bolts off while tightening.  That would be a longitudinal/pulling force, exactly what the bolt is designed for.

@Criggie Yes I agree, but it is also obvious that bolts are not intended to be used after they got damaged. I just noticed that I previously overread the description where the same happened also to the not loose bolts, so my answer can't be the reason for his problem.

Bolts are designed to withstand force along the pulling direction, but they are not intended to withstand forces to the side   -  wow.  if it wasn't early monday morning i'd rip this apart with examples and test this site's interpretation of inappropriate verbage

who upvotes something like this?  follow the science i guess

Hard to see with the angled picture, but it looks like the top two bolts have failed plastically with necking:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necking_(engineering)
This can only have occurred if there was a fixed end point at the other end of the bolt. Possible causes could include:

Bad/mismatched threads either in the fastener or in the threaded hole, these jammed during tighten/removal.
High corrosion of the fastener/receptacle, causing the fastener/receptacle pair to bind.
Over-tightening, causing deformation during install (rather than removal)
The body of the bolt was insufficiently strong to handle the expected forces from expected force levels between the thread thread and the receptacle (least likely - should run smoothly in normal operation).

Over-tightening/force shouldn't really apply when removing the bolts, so it would have to have happened during the initial assembly - someone else mentioned installing with a torque wrench, but this only works if you've an idea of a suitable torque.
I'd recommend using an anti-sieze compound during assembly next time, to reduce binding. I'd also make sure you use an SS fastener for high-corrosion applications. They are a bit more expensive, and are softer (Austenite vs ferrite), but if installed with an anti-seize compound, shouldn't seize.
If money is no limit you can use Silver-plated fasteners :) - no anti-seize necessary.
P.S. a good stainless should work harden, so necking should be minimal - which doesn't seem to be the case here, pending better side-on photos
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_hardening
